# how can i display specific characters from a field in SQL?

Tags: sql, string, reporting-services, substring, character

This is for a report in SSRS.
currently it displays a rather long array inside a field called [**userSignUpAnswers**] which looks a bit like this:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSignUpQuestionInfo xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SignUpQuestionInfo><EventSignUpQuestionId>1002</EventSignUpQuestionId><QuestionName>What is the nature of your appointment?</QuestionName><Answers><EventSignUpQuestionOptionId>13</EventSignUpQuestionOptionId>
<UserSelectedValue>**Retirement**</UserSelectedValue>
<PriceAdjustment>0.0000</PriceAdjustment></Answers></SignUpQuestionInfo></ArrayOfSignUpQuestionInfo>
```

I am only interested in the **userSelectedValue** above. This comes from a drop down list which users select (there are about 6 options).

So I was either thinking of selecting the 250th character from the above field to about the 260th character or if i could display whatever characters are in between the  tags that would be good.

i've been trying charindex and substring without any success.
any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in SSRS as an Expression then you can use this..

```
=
LEFT (
    MID(Fields!myField.Value, Instr(Fields!myField.Value, "<UserSelectedValue>") + 19),
    Instr(MID(Fields!myField.Value, Instr(Fields!myField.Value, "<UserSelectedValue>") + 19), "</UserSelectedValue>")-1
    )
```

19 refers to the length of the first string you want to find `<UserSelectedValue>`

There might be a more elegant way but this does work. If you want to do it in sql then you could do the following

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
                myField,
                CHARINDEX('<UserSelectedValue>', myField) + 19,
                CHARINDEX('</UserSelectedValue>', myField, CHARINDEX('<UserSelectedValue>', myField) + 19) - (CHARINDEX('<UserSelectedValue>', myField) + 19)
            )
```

again, probably a much more elegant way of doing it

Comment: thanks, I tried the sql above like this:

`
'SELECT        SUBSTRING(userSignUpAnswers, CHARINDEX('<UserSelectedValue>', userSignUpAnswers) + 9, CHARINDEX('</UserSelectedValue>', userSignUpAnswers, CHARINDEX('<UserSelectedValue>', userSignUpAnswers) + 9) '
                         - (CHARINDEX('<UserSelectedValue>', userSignUpAnswers) + 9)) AS Expr1
FROM            dbo.tblNaDevEventsUsersSignedUpToEvent
`
but that returned an error:

Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Comment: It shoud be `+19` not `+9`. 19 represents the length of the string we are searching for as we need the position at the end of that string. You might also get this error when the string cannot be found. You can test this by adding a where clause something like `WHERE userSignUpAnswers  NOT LIKE('%<UserSelectedValue>%')`

Comment: I see, sorry, i thought that it was the length of the string inside the <userSelectedValue> so thought i could change it to smaller number.
anyway I changed it back to 19 and tried the where clause too but still got the same error.

i think we might can the idea of using the drop down list and just use a text field instead. but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: my mistake, the WHERE clause should have read  `WHERE userSignUpAnswers  LIKE('%<UserSelectedValue>%')` , not sure how `NOT` ended up in there

Comment: i'm sorry it doesn't let me vote for the answer, says my reputation isn't 15. hopefully someone else will vote for this or i will when i am allowed to. thanks again

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, then you accept it rather than vote. That's the check mark under the vote up/down buttons. You earn reputation for doing this too.